# expected `secure_user.birth_date` to have changed from "1990-01-01" to "2000-01-01", but did not change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

Here is my rspec test code

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Users::PaymentController, type: :controller do

  let(:user) { create(:user) }
  let(:secure_user) { create(:secure_user, user_id: user.id, email: 'abc123@mail.com', birth_date: '1990-01-01', gender: 'female', nation: 'jp', prefecture: 'Tokyo-to', municipality: 'Shibuya-ku') }

  describe 'POST #create' do
    params = {
      birth_date: '2000-01-01',
      gender: 'male',
      prefecture: 'Osaka-fu',
      municipality: 'Osaka-shi'
    }
    it "changes secure_user's attributes" do
      expect do
        post :create, params: params
      end.to change{ secure_user.birth_date }.from('1990-01-01').to('2000-01-01')
    end
  end

end
```

and here is the related part from Users::PaymentController

```
     module Users
       class PaymentController < Users::BaseController
    
         def create
           current_user.secure_user.update(user_personal_info_params)
           ......
           ......
         end
    
         private
    
         def user_personal_info_params
           params.permit(:birth_date, :gender, :nation, :prefecture, :municipality)
         end

       end
     end
```

The logic is: add new info to `current_user.secure_user` while `payment` is created.
But the test fails and I don't know the reason.

```
  1) Users::PaymentController POST #create changes secure_user's attributes
     Failure/Error:
       expect do
         post :create, params: user_info
         binding.pry
       end.to change{ secure_user.birth_date }.from('1990-01-01').to('2000-01-01')
     
       expected `secure_user.birth_date` to have changed from "1990-01-01" to "2000-01-01", but did not change
```

I am not very familiar with RSpec (and so does English), much appreciated if anybody could help me solve this problem.

Comment: maybe im missing something but what is ```secure_user``` here? At least it look like you are updating that, not the user...

Comment: @Haumer  Thanks for the reply! `secure_user` is a model which belongs to `user`. so if I want to update secure_user, what should I change?

Comment: sorry, it might just have been me being sloppy here. is **birth_date** supposed to be a string? do the other values (gender, prefecture, municipality) change? you could check that in your binding.pry

Comment: @Haumer Yes, `birth_date` is a string, so does other values. And I checked my binding.pry but none of these values change.

Comment: put your binding.pry on the line after you update (in the controller) and then try ```current_user.secure_user.valid?```and ```current_user.secure_user.errors.full_messages``` whats the output?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `.reload`

```rb
...
end.to change{ secure_user.reload.birth_date }.from('1990-01-01').to('2000-01-01')
```

The object doesn't get updated inside the test, you have to reload it, to have the up to date attributes.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! but my test still goes  


1) Users::PaymentController POST #create changes secure_user's attributes
     Failure/Error:
       expect do
         post :create, params: params
       end.to change{ secure_user.reload.birth_date }.from('1990-01-01').to('2000-01-01')
     
       expected `secure_user.reload.birth_date` to have changed from "1990-01-01" to "2000-01-01", but did not change

Comment: I think you're missing a fragment where you sign in the user before this request? Check the other controller tests how they do it. I suspect that's the case because you're using `current_user` in the controller, but in the test I don't see you sign in any user.